# rust solana build error: no such subcommand: +bpf

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, parrot-os, solana

I am new to solana and rust, recently i have installed thier example-helloworld from this repo- https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld .
Whenever i have tried to build the rust program using npm scripts or going to the rust program directory to manually run *cargo build-bpf*, it says - no such subcommand: +bpf.[terminal error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7RtQ.png)

i have also tried the command **which cargo-build-bpf**,it have no error.
however i have also tried to manually build using *cargo build* ,it throws a error.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: did u figure it out?

Comment: For anyone coming to this later it is caused by installing rust improperly (such as through apt). You can fix it by uninstalling rust and installing it through https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install

Comment: did you update `PATH`?

Comment: Running `solana-keygen new` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 11):

Your version of Rust may be out of date, can you try updating to Rust 1.53?  You should be able to get it using:

```
rustup toolchain add 1.53
```

You might then need to reinstall the Solana tool suite, following the instructions at: https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools#use-solanas-install-tool